# Why my service on linux, consumes so much CPU?

Tags: linux, bash, services

I created an service in linux, sshield, for protecting of brute force attacks via ssh. My service is finished, and all run well.

But ... I saw a little detail. This service consumes so much CPU!

[image: image: sshield's CPU in server]

[image: image: sshield's CPU in desktop]

It consumes 20.6%, it is so much

My service run in flat second a while loop infinity. Could it causes is so much CPU's up? Else What could it is?

Github: https://github.com/cleanet/sshield
Review sshield: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rj4j7VqXXI

## MODIFICATION | 3/1/2020 at 13:09

I edited my script, deleting the follow:

```
lineas_antiguas=$(wc -l /var/log/auth.log);
IFS=" " read -ra lineas_antiguas <<< $lineas_antiguas;
```

Adding constants:

```
declare -r SSHIELD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/sshield.log"
declare -r AUTH_LOG_FILE="/var/log/auth.log"
```

And replacing the  paths by it.
Also, I replace the while loop by:

```
tail -F -n 0 "$AUTH_LOG_FILE" | while read line
do
   ...
done
```

And deleting:

```
lineas=$(wc -l /var/log/auth.log);
IFS=" " read -ra lineas <<< $lineas;
linea_contenido=$(tail -n 1 /var/log/auth.log);
```

My script is updated in my GITHUB

The result is that, it doesn't consume so much CPU and Memory
[image]
0.3% CPU and 0.2% RAM

But. Why the service is duplicated
[image]

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel in an inappropriate shell language that is inefficiently parsing log files, loop reads. fail2ban is native efficient code https://www.fail2ban.org/

Comment: Shell is not the best tool for such a service.  Other languages are better suited and will run much faster, with less CPU usage.  Look at existing tools, and try , https://serverfault.com/,  you might have better chance.  That being said, here on SO you should post a  specific issue with your code, and provide a [mcve].  As is, it is out of scope to go through your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you are **constantly** counting lines in the file `/var/log/auth.log` from the beginning, and doing stuff:

```
while [ TRUE ]
do

    lineas=$(wc -l /var/log/auth.log);
   ...
    ip_logueada=$(wc -l /var/log/auth.log | grep -E -o "[0-9]{1,9}")
   ....
done
```

So it's not just the CPU but the hard drive that is under stress.

If you really must process the log file from the beginning to count lines or gather statistics, do it only once when your script starts, do not repeat this operation in a loop, it is wasteful and unnecessary.

What you want is some sort of **tail** on that file you're monitoring.
So you could have something like:

```
tail -n0 -F /var/log/auth.log | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  # do something
done
```

This snippet will echo the new lines as they are written to the file. So you just have to 'listen' to the stream of new lines, parse them and keep track of offending IP addresses. This approach should solve your performance issues.

A bit of advice: use variable names for the source and target files. For example `/var/log/auth.log` is repeated multiple times in your code, so is `/var/log/sshield.log`.

You can add a few variables at the beginning of your script, even declare them as **constants** (read-only variables) like this:

```
declare -r SOURCE_LOG_FILE="/var/log/auth.log"
```

And then you can simply write: `tail -n0 -F "$SOURCE_LOG_FILE"`. Thus you avoid repetition.

I would also **divide the code** in a few function blocks. For example, you can have:

- one function for sending the mail
- another function to keep track of the counters: you pass an IP address and it checks how many violations were recorded over the current session, and blocks the IP address if the threshold was met.

That would make the code more clear and easier to maintain. Right now the flow is not easy to follow and the code is all over the place.

You should also have a function for **logging** alerts to your file `/var/log/sshield.log`. You have many **repetitive** lines like:

```
echo "logged ip: $ip_logueada - $(date)" >> /var/log/sshield.log
```

Create a function, then just pass the text to be logged as argument, and let the function add the timestamp and write the text to the file, formatted the way you want. You can streamline the code a lot by getting rid of **redundancy**.

Now I have to agree that you are reinventing the wheel, there are free tools that do more and more efficiently. The exercise is good for education purposes though.

Comment: I changed all it that you explained me and the service doesn't consume so much! The average is 0.3%. Thanks you very much. It runs more light. Even if, Why the service is duplicated?

Comment: You are welcome. The code suddenly looks quite easier to read. I don't know how you've configured your service, perhaps need to uninstall the previous version ? I think the main loop should do very little really, just parse the new lines as they come, if there is a malicious attempt, extract the IP address and pass it to another function. As others had said doing it in pure bash is not easy. Also this script does IPv4 only but your server may also have IPv6 addresses. You are not protecting against IPv6 attacks. A more in-depth analysis belongs to the Code review Site I think.

Comment: My service have an uninstaller, for easy your use. This is more by comfort, that by need. If, I will add code for that, also, it protects of brute force's attack with IPv6

Comment: I updated this, and the service support protection for IPv4 and IPv6. https://github.com/cleanet/sshield. But, why the service run with two processes?